# How can I repair and waterproof a large crack in my foundation wall?

Tags: basement, foundation, waterproofing, exterior, cement

I recently just bought a house which was nice at first!  Now after 5 month, it is now spring. We had a good rainfall which flooded my basement from the floor up because of a high water table (sump pump runs quite frequently) and a Crack in a corner in the floor. When digging the next day on the exterior of the basement wall,  we found that one of the cracks in the foundation is actually worse when uncovered! This Crack is the size of the whole basement foundation (roughly 6 ft vertical) along with a decent hole.

Repair:

Is it OK to fill up the gap inside the cement block all the way up the wall with cement

Any other solutions you guys can provide

[image]

Comment: So I repaired the wall by simply digging 6 ft around the corner and about 10 ft to the right. I got an impact hammer and broke all the crappy cinder blocks. then precisionly used a flat head and hammer to knock the mortar out of joints. Went to a construction warehouse (not a homedepot or lowes since their "cement blocks" are complete shit and not right for the job. filled the semi solid blocks with cement and put them as the first block to foundation. then layed the rest of the blocks and then poured concrete in them with rebar. No leak where I worked...

Answer (score 1):

If your question is simply "is it ok", sure, it's ok. It may not seal the leak, though, and it may crack again if your home experiences seasonal movement due to an inadequately deep foundation or other issues.

You should probably consult with a local expert to find a solution that's appropriate for your climate and soil, and not throw darts at the problem. An exterior patch along with a waterproof membrane might be cheaper, easier, and less expensive, for example.

Comment: Well hopefully their is an engineer on this site that can point in the right direction for repair options.

Comment: An engineer needs the information I mentioned in my answer, which is why I didn't offer more in the way of a custom solution. You might edit your post to add some detail. Also change the question you're asking to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your best bet is patch that crack and install a french drain around area, keep the water from getting to that foundation.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Can you edit your answer to include how the crack should be repaired?